# Series of if statements vs nested if statements?

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

Just wondering if there is any difference between a series of if statements separated out from one another, versus a bunch of nested if statements where each one is indented in from the previous? Is the same fall through applicable?

Comment: While I didn't down vote, your question needs a lot of work (hence the down votes). You don't give any examples of what you mean and your question is largely opinion based (opinion based questions are generally off topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several styles of if statements.
1. "Bushy":

```
if(cond1)
     {
     if(cond2)
          {
          if(cond3)
               action123;
          else action123b;
          }
     else {
          if(cond3b)
               action12b3;
          else action12b3b;
          }
     }
else {
     /* ... */
     }
```

2: Long if/else chain:

```
if(cond1)
    {
    action 1;
    }
else if(cond2)
    {
    action 2;
    }
else if(cond3)
    {
    action 3;
    }
else if(cond4)
    /* ... */
```

Long if/else chain with "rigid" indentation:

```
if(cond1)
     {
     action 1;
     }
else {
     if(cond2)
          {
          action 2;
          }
     else {
          if(cond3)
               {
               action 3;
               }
          else {
               /* ... */
```

As far as I'm concerned, the general consensus on good programming style is that "bushy" trees like #1 are poor -- they've *very* hard to understand.  (They're barely understandable if they're 2 levels deep, difficult to understand at three, and essentially impossible at 4.)

The general consensus is that a long if/else chain as in #2 is much, much easier to understand.  It's such an obvious idiom that it's worth presenting it the way I did in #2, *not* the more "logical" presentation as in #3.

Bushy trees can be so hard to understand that I sometimes convert them into the chained if/else form:

```
if(cond1 && cond2)
     {
     /* action if both true */
     }
else if(cond1 && !cond2)
     {
     /* action if only cond1 true */
     }
else if(!cond1 && cond2)
     {
     /* action if only cond2 true */
     }
else {
     /* action if neither true */
     }
```

This is "less efficient" in that `cond1` and `cond2` might be evaluated multiple times, but in doing so it trades off CPU cycles (which are cheap) against programmer time (which is expensive) and bugs (which can be even more expensive).

Answer (score 2):

The key is making sure you get the results that you intend.  If all of the things that you are testing are logically independent, then you could just have all of your if statements in a line.  Often times, however, the conditions being tested are inter-related; and then it is often simpler to express that logic using nested if statements.

It is well worth creating test cases to exercise all the possible paths through your logic to ensure that your conditional code gives you the results that you want in all circumstances.

Your most important considerations are having your code function correctly -- closely followed by having your code be easily understood by those who will have to maintain it.  Performance considerations would only come into it after those goals were achieved if measurements proved that this stretch of code consumed significant time.

Answer (score 2):

This would entirely depend on your specific case.  It is very tough to help you without seeing any examples of your situation.

In general, having multiple `if` conditions in series would add to execution time, and would be considered trivial logic.

It would be better if you can reorganize your logic so as to either use nested if conditions, or even better choose other control logics such as `switch` or `for`.