# Nullptr check practice : nested if statement vs series of nullptr check

Tags: c++

while I was writing some code, I found out there are two types of convention(or coding style) in terms of checking nullptr, when series of objects should be non-null.
Here how it goes :

#### Style 1

```
if (auto parent = ParentSpawner())
{
    if (auto child = parent->ChildSpawner())
    {
        if (auto grandChild = child->GrandChildSpawner())
        {
            // Do something...
            grandChild->DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Style 2

```
auto parent = ParentSpawner();
if (nullptr == parent)
    return;

auto child = parent->ChildSpawner();
if (nullptr == child)
    return;

auto grandChild = child->GrandChildSpawner();
if (nullptr == grandChild)
    return;

// Do something...
grandChild->DoSomething();
```

Which one should I prefer?

Plus, in `Style 1`, is there any overhead due to implicit casting inside of *if statement*? (from nullptr->bool)

(+ I found similar question in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755153/series-of-if-statements-vs-nested-if-statements))

Comment: Neither. I would consider both to be bad, for different reasons.

Comment: @sweenish Hello, then what would you do in the above situation? Please give me some advide 

Comment: Both are ok, though the yoda conditions in (2) are unnecessary because modern compilers should warn on `=` instead of `==` regardless. I would use (1), but keep only the innermost braces, and unindent inner `if`s to be on the same level as the outermost one.

Comment: Read up on the law of Demeter.

Comment: If the thing to do when all conditions are satisfied is as short as in the given example, I would use Style 1. But if there is a lot more to do, then I would prefer Style 2 (not the Yoda conditions, though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the implicit conversion, there shall be no overhead as this will be checked compile time, [see cpp reference on implicit conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion)

> An expression e is said to be implicitly convertible to T2 if and only if T2 can be copy-initialized from e, that is the declaration T2 t = e; is well-formed (can be compiled), for some invented temporary t.

As for your second question regarding style. My suggestiong is purely a preference and will not be objective at all, neither based on any performance related facts.

**Nested If Style 1**

I would personnally prefer having this style if there is a clear dependence between the nested statements, it does make sense in your example, so I would go with Style 1.

**Multiple point of exit Style 2**

I usually go with that style when the various checks are not related to each other and cannot be combined in the same if. That doesn't happen too often.